# How to fix: injecting singleton service into SignalR hub causing problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I injected singleton service in SignalR hub to save client details, while the connection is active,

```
    Client.Client(_memory.Player.ConnectionId).SendAsync("registerComplete")
```

causes multiple requests, for example, for the first time Angular client logs once, after refresh or invoking another function, number of logs increase by 1

I wanted to create private variables in signal r hub, but then read that hubs are stateless and tried injecting singleton class named HubMemory, but as mentioned before this causes duplicate requests

I don't want to make _memory static, want every player hub to have its own memory.

```cs
    private LoggingManager _logger;
    private object _syncRoot = new object();

    private IHubContext<PlayerConnectionHub> _context;
    private HubMemory _memory;

    public PlayerConnectionHub(IHubContext<PlayerConnectionHub> hubContext, HubMemory memory)
    {
        _logger = new LoggingManager();
        _context = hubContext;
        _memory = memory;
    }

    public short RegisterClient(string userName, long accountId)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            Player.Player player;
            if (Players.ContainsKey(accountId))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                player = new Player.Player
                {
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    UserName = userName,
                    AccountId = accountId
                };
                Players.Add(accountId, player);
                _memory.Player = player;
            }
            player.Online = true;
            _context.Clients.Client(_memory.Player.ConnectionId).SendAsync("registerComplete");
            _logger.LogPlayers(Players);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This in browser console, onRegisterComplete logs registerComplete, but after refreshing or invoking another time RegisterClient logs two times and numbers raise.

Comment: From the MS documentaion page: Hubs are transient. Don't store state in a property on the hub class. Every hub method call is executed on a new hub instance. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @bdongus  yes i know that, I am trying to send data to a specific connected client, for example, client connected the hub, and after that something in the server happened in background worker, how would I be able to notify the specific client ?

Comment: I think the hub is the wrong place to handle this. Your background worker needs to know which client(s) to inform. From there I would send whatever message you what to send. Sending a message from outside the hub is documented on the MS pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. what = want.